# Unable to assign untyped int to generic struct field

Tags: go, generics

Given a generic struct:

```
type R2[IDTYPE comparable] struct {
    ID        IDTYPE
    IsActive  bool
}
```

Implementing an interface:

```
type Storable interface {
    Store(ctx context.Context) error
}
```

I would expect the following definition to work:

```
func (r R2[int]) Store(ctx context.Context) error {
    r.ID = 123 // not allowed
    // ...
    return nil
}
```

However, the method definition is not allowed. The error is:

```
'123' (type untyped int) cannot be represented by the type IDTYPE (int)
```

Is it not yet possible to do this kind of generic field assignment in Go?

Addendum:
On go playground the error is:

```
cannot use 123 (untyped int constant) as int value in assignment
```

And converting to `int(123)` does not work. The error in this case is:

```
cannot use comparable(123) (untyped int constant 123) as int value in assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instantiation](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations) must happen at the type level, not on a method level, and methods can't introduce new type parameters, see [How to create generic method in Go? (method must have no type parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668236/how-to-create-generic-method-in-go-method-must-have-no-type-parameters/70668559#70668559)

This means when you want to use `R2`, you then have to choose type arguments for the type parameters, and the methods can't change those, you're "stuck" with the types you choose on `R2`'s instantiation.

Also note that since the constraint for `IDTYPE` is `comparable`, which may be `string` for example, the integer `123` cannot be assigned to the `ID` field in all cases because it may have a type of `string`.

If you want / must handle multiple concrete types for the IDs, generics is not the right choice. Interfaces may be used instead:

```
type R2 struct {
    ID       any
    IsActive bool
}
```

Also note that the receiver must be a pointer if you wish to modify the receiver (e.g. fields of a struct).

If you wish to restrict the values stored in `ID` to `comparable`, use a (generic) function for it.

Here's how you can do it:

```
type R2 struct {
    ID       any
    IsActive bool
}

func (r *R2) Store(ctx context.Context) error {
    setID(r, 123)
    return nil
}

func setID[ID comparable](r *R2, id ID) {
    r.ID = id
}
```

Testing it:

```
r := &R2{}
var s Storable = r

s.Store(context.TODO())

fmt.Println(r)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KQJDpYig6W5)):

```
&{123 false}
```

This provides flexibility (you can set any comparable values to the `ID` field using `setID()`), and provides compile-time safety: attempting to set an incomparable value will result in a compile-time error such as this:

```
setID(r, []int{1}) // Error: []int does not implement comparable
```